# 'Can't connect to this network' TP-Link Archer T9E

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, home-networking

I know others have posted similar questions, but I have tried all the proposed solutions I am able to.

I have a desktop computer, and an TP-Link Archer T9E. Ever since I have upgraded to windows 10, I seem to be nonstop wrestling with the card to get it to work properly.

I also have a regular old Belkin Wifi adapter, which connects to all networks fine. The Archer gets far better connection, to the point where I can't really use it very well without it.

The Archer refuses to connect to the access point closest to me displaying 'Can't connect to this network', but will connect directly to the modem several floors down. Solutions tried:

Uninstalling the device, rebooting windows, then manually installing the drivers from manufacturers website.

Restarting the access point and anything related to it.

Forgetting the network and re-attempting to join it (Ever since a windows 10 update, it just started asking me if I want my PC to be discoverable on the network, something I can't recall happening before.)

Enabling and disabling the device.

Updating drivers through windows system (Just said I had the best available drivers)

Althought after about a half an hour of googling, people are saying switching the PCI port or installing this Windows10 update:
http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4073290

will help fix the problem. I'm going to attempt these things, and see how it goes. I am just posting because I have a feeling a lot of other people have this issue.

Update: After both moving the adapter to a new PCI slot, and installing the new update, it still isn't working.

This is extremely frustrating, as I've been trying to fix this for about 5+ hours now.

Edit: Seems like I can see the adapter resetting itself now when trying to connect (Wasn't doing this before) then tries connect again, and gives the same error.

It still has no problems connecting to my modem directly, which is 2 floors below me. I just recently tried shutting down my pc, turning off the wireless access point, then my modem, then turning them back on and turning my PC back on to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Just after some Googling, I noticed your post. I basically have the same issue with the T9E TP Link card and have tried all of the methods you listed as well. What was strange is that it was working fine for 2 years, and then the other day it just decided to start not functioning properly.

The only way I can get it to connect to a network now is by removing all 3 antennas from the card. It will have a poor signal, but I can still get about 15Mbs down on my connection. If, after connected to the network, I install just one of the three antennas, it may stay connected for 5-10 minutes, but then windows will say "No internet access", and then just drop the connection all together and revert to the "Can't connect to network" issue.

So, at this point I have ordered a Rosewill card, basically the same card just Rosewill. I will see if this card works any better.

UPDATE:

So I basically purchased the Rosewill version of the TP-Link card. It's the exact same card, just branded by Rosewill. I installed it, and installed the Rosewill driver. The card worked prefectly fine for about 4 days. I left for the weekend, and shut down my computer. I came back 2 days later, booted up my computer, and the same exact issue started happening on this card. It connected, and would say "no internet access". Then it would just disconnect completely. When I try to reconnect to the network, it would say "Can't connect to network". Then, I remove all of the three antennas from the card, and like magic, the computer has no issues connecting to the network, and staying connected. It just has really weak signal because of the disconnected antennas.

So, at this point I think it has to be the card, or a Windows 10 driver issue. Either way, it's very annoying that they have not identified this issue and solved it yet.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's 3 years late, but I've got a fix.
First you have to download the driver mentioned in this page:
https://community.tp-link.com/en/home/forum/topic/204498?fbclid=IwAR33oT9VjdsGEZZTkgs0uR07bbmCbQy4IeVWQ-Rm_crY3W9_7QVYSClKk8g

Especifically: https://static.tp-link.com/2019/201911/20191129/Archer T6E T9E_ASUS driver_7.35.351.0.zip

Then you have to install it using this instructions: https://www.tp-link.com/support/faq/2722/

After that, remove the middle antenna, you have to leave only the edge antennas.
If your problem was similar to mine, then you'll be able to connect to your wifi again.